# Question about a selected style of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I set the Property of UITableview - "Show Selection On Touch" to YES in Interface Builder.
But when I selected a row, the cell's style just changed its color to blue.

In some app which contains UITableview, when user selected a row,it will appear a '√' to represent that this row is selected.

I want to know how can I get this effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `accessoryType` property to toggle between `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` together with `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to do the toggling.

For details and examples, please see this post: [UITableView, having problems changing accessory when selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974170/uitableview-having-problems-changing-accessory-when-selected)

Comment: I'm assuming this would be helpful as well for the type of application your building. If you don't want the cell to be blue when it's selected set its `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Answer (score 0):

In

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tV didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

do:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tV cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```